# How to count values in a column of datagridview column and show in other column

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, count, datagridview

In a DataGridView I need to count how many duplicate values a column has.

for example This is my Datagridview:

| Personal | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 130001 | 2 |
| 130001 |  |
| 130002 | 3 |
| 130002 |  |
| 130002 |  |

For example, I'd like to count how many "personalCode" I have in my "Personal" column, and put the result in a first row of each PersonalCode in Count column.
130001=2
130002=3

Comment: In the underlying DataTable you can use linq to group by the records by person and get the count. Ofcourse it needs to be selected into a different dataTable and bind to the main DataGridView..you can also run a for loop along the records to get the count

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you remove the extra duplicate strings and leave only the unique values?
[image]

```
List<uint> codes = new List<uint>()
{
    { 130001 },
    { 130001 },
    { 130002 },
    { 130002 },
    { 130002 },
};

DataTable table = new DataTable();
List<DataColumn> keys = new List<DataColumn>(2);

DataColumn personalColumn = new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = "Personal",
    DataType = typeof(uint)
};
DataColumn countColumn = new DataColumn()
{
    ColumnName = "Count",
    DataType = typeof(int)
};

table.Columns.Add(personalColumn);
table.Columns.Add(countColumn);

keys.Add(personalColumn);
keys.Add(countColumn);

table.PrimaryKey = keys.ToArray();

codes.Distinct().ToList().ForEach(code =>
{
    table.Rows.Add(code, codes.Where(x => x == code).Count());
});

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```